# Appending and accessing a counter within a counter within a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, counter

I would like to do counter within a counter within a dictionary. What would be the code to make this possible? This is what I have so far:

```
Dict1 = {'1234': {[number, msg1, line1],[number,msg1,line1],[number,msg1,line2]}, '2345':{[number,msg2,line1]}}

Dict2 = {'1234': {msg1:3}, '2345': {msg2:line1}}
for key in dict1:
    dict2.setdefault(str(key),[]).append(dict(Counter(i[1] for i in dict1[key]
```

---

I want Dict2 to return this and to be able to call the lines and msgs:

```
Dict2 = {'1234': {msg1: {line1:2, line2:1}, '2345':{msg2: {line1:1}}
```

I was thinking of something like this, but it says that dict2[key][[i] is not valid syntax:

```
if i[3] for i in dict1[key] for key in dict1:
    dict2[key][i].append(Counter(i[3] for i in dict1[key]))
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I would like to do counter within a counter within a dictionary." Why do you need to do this? It sounds unnecessarily complicated just from that description.

Comment: _"it says that dict2[key][[i] is not valid syntax:"_ Syntax errors sometimes misreport the line by one. It's your `if` condition that's invalid syntax.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense I am going through error logs and and capturing specific data. I need to figure out the specific lines in a message that are causing an error to occur.

Comment: @kevin I will try to change the the if statement and see if the issue persists. Thanks